# Woocommerce rest api stops working suddenly

Tags: android, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, oauth

Rest API was giving results but suddenly it stops giving result and giving me this error instead:

> "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
> "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
> "data": {
> "status": 401
> }

I'm using oAuth1 with the correct key and secret. Using this version "WordPress 5.4.2" and
"WooCommerce 4.4.1".

Comment: The HTTP 401 Unauthorized client error status response code indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

This status is sent with a WWW-Authenticate header that contains information on how to authorize correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving API-Keys in Params https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=123&consumer_secret=123

Comment: tried it but still the same problem, actually! I'm facing this problem with all the other projects which are using woocommerce.